# Importing MaterialIcon in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I used below import statement in my angular project. But it is not working:

```js
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
```

Comment: Please specify the error you are encountering.

Comment: Hi Kamalka, welcome to SO! We can better help you if you include 1) what error you are having, 2) what research you have already done to try and fix it, and 3) minimum reproducible code. Please edit your question including these details. Thank you!

Comment: ok.I will update it.

Comment: It should be `MatIconModule`, not `MaterialIconModule`: https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're putting this reference in your module file, such as `app.module.ts`.  It does not go in your `component` file.

```js
/* app.module.ts | Angular 9.x */
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatIconModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    MatIconModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note: you can also put this in a different module file if you are organizing your modules differently; however, I've shown this in the root module here, so it would be available globally, in this example.

Make sure you also load the font.  Adding it to the `HEAD` section of your `index.html` file is easiest.
http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web (method 1)

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, you would use this in your component HTML as normal:

```html
<mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
```

More info: https://material.angular.io/components/icon

Comment: Angular material shows errors and tells missing files. i am using angular 8 and node 13.5.0 . Are they not compatible or is there something I missed?

Comment: They didn’t really change anything here in Angular 9.  Make sure you also load the font.  It’s easiest todo this in the HEAD section of your index.html file.  http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web

Answer (score 1):

In addition to import `MatIconModule` into the module where is declared your component in which you want to use the icons:

```js
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule,
  ]
})
export class ExampleModule { }
```

You must include Material Icons font to your `index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Application</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- include Material Icons font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll be able to use the icons like this:

```html
<mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
```

You can find a complete list of available icons here: https://material.io/resources/icons/

> ⚡ Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-60028622